# How to use a Nuget package that was not installed?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I started looking at a new codebase... it's an existing API that is currently using the "using directive" to access classes in a different namespace. This package is use in other API and services and typically is installed via Nuget. For this specific API, I found that it does not have the package installed but it IS importing the package using the using directive and also accessing some contract models and queries from the package.

I'm relatively new to C# but am just wondering.. are there other ways to import nuget packages without having to install them? I'm not sure why this is working. There are no visual studio/compiler/build errors.

Comment: Is another NuGet package referencing the one in question as a dependency?  It's not uncommon for only a few NuGet package references to result in dozens of available assemblies.

Comment: You can also add references to assemblies itself without a nuget package. Perhaps a developer added only the used (copied) dll as the whole packet was too much for him/her